# Convert Excel Date to Date while preserving "non Date" strings in the same column

Tags: r, excel, date

I have a specific column in my dataset that contains both dates and text. Because of this, the read_xls function I am using imports the entire column as class "character." Hence, the dates revert to their underlying date code in excel (43348, 43347, etc).

An example vector of my data and what I am trying to accomplish is as follows:

```
> x<- c("43347", "43348", "OPEN")
> x<- as.Date(x, format = "%m/%d/%Y", origin = "1899-12-30")
```

The result is that all values in x become "NA".

Does anyone know how I can instruct R to only change the 43347 and 43348 to their specified date and leave "OPEN" as is? Should I use something other than read_xls?

Disclaimer: I am working with a large dataset so it would not be practical to split the column manually like:

```
> x1<- c(43347, 43348)
> y1<- c("OPEN")
```

Imagine this vector with 1500+ values.

Comment: What do you want the data type of this column to be? R does not support mixed types in a data.frame column (at least not without resorting to a list column which makes working with it much more difficult). Do you want them all just to be character values in the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This what you want?

data:

```
x <- c("43347", "43348", "OPEN")
```

code:

```
ifelse(is.na(as.numeric(x)),x, as.character(as.Date(as.numeric(x), origin = "1899-12-30")))
```

result:

```
#[1] "2018-09-04" "2018-09-05" "OPEN"
```

---

Faster version:

```
IND <- !is.na(as.numeric(x))
x[IND] <- as.character(format(as.Date(as.numeric(x[IND]), origin = "1899-12-30"), format = "%m/%d/%Y"))
remove(IND)
x
#[1] "09/04/2018" "09/05/2018" "OPEN"
```